# Comparing the metrics -current month, previous month and previous year same month

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a query that would fetch the metrics for the current month and the same metric for the previous month and the same metric for the previous year last month . I have the data available in the table only from Jan 2021. Please find below the sample data

Sample Input

| Archive | State | purchase | requests | purchaserate | fulfilledrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | AK | 1500 | 1300 | 115.0 | 80.0 |
| 2/1/2022 | AL | 20000 | 17000 | 117.0 | 90.0 |
| 1/1/2022 | AK | 1700 | 1400 | 121.0 | 65.0 |
| 1/1/2022 | AL | 25000 | 27000 | 93.0 | 89.0 |
| 2/1/2021 | AK | 2100 | 3000 | 70.0 | 50.0 |
| 2/1/2021 | AL | 32000 | 26000 | 123.0 | 60.0 |

Sample Output

| Archive | State | purchasecurrentmonth | purchasepreviousmonth | purchasepreviouyearsamemonth | purchaseratecurrentmonth | purchaseratepreviousmonth | purchaseratepreviousyearsamemonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | AK | 1500 | 1700 | 2100.0 | 115.0 | 121 | 70 |
| 2/1/2022 | AL | 20000 | 25000 | 32000.0 | 117.0 | 93 | 123 |

```
create table ##input 
(archive date, state varchar(10), purchase int, purchaserate float, fulfilledrate float)
 insert into ##input values 
('2/1/2022','AK','1500','115','80'),
 ('2/1/2022','AL','20000','117','90'),
 ('1/1/2022','AK','1700','121','65'), 
('1/1/2022','AL','25000','93','89'),
 ('2/1/2021','AK','2100','70','50'), 
('2/1/2021','AL','32000','123','60')
Output
create table ##output 
(archive date, 
state varchar(10), 
purchaseincreasedecrease-MOM float, 
purchaseincreasedecrease-YOM float, 
purchaserate -MOM float, 
purchaserate -YOM float, 
fulfilledrate-MOM float, 
fulfilledrate-YOM float)
insert into ##output values 
('2/1/2022','AK','-11.7','-28.6','-6','45','15','30'), 
('2/1/2022','AL','-20','-37.5','24','-6','1','30')
```

I have been trying the following code: Any guidance would be helpful:

```
SELECT 
        c.archive, 
        c.state, 
        c.purchase AS curr_month_purchase,
        c1.purchase as prev_month_purchase,
        c12.purchase as same_month_of_prev_year_purchase,
        c.purchaserate AS curr_month_purchaserate,
        c1.purchaserate as prev_month_purchaserate,
        c12.purchaserate as same_month_of_prev_year_purchaserate,
        c.fulfilledrate AS curr_month_fulfilledrate,
        c1.fulfilledrate as prev_month_fulfilledrate,
        c12.fulfilledrate as same_month_of_prev_year_fulfilledrate
    FROM CTE_Sum AS c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT * FROM CTE_Sum WHERE archive = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, c.archive) AND state = c.state
    ) AS c1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT * FROM CTE_Sum WHERE archive = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, c.archive) AND state = c.state
    ) AS c12
)
```

Now for Jan 2021 I cannot have any previous month data and also for the entire 2021 I cannot have previous year data.Any Inputs here will be helpful. Also wanted to understand how does cross apply transfer to Bigquery

Comment: You could start by changing `cross apply` to `outer apply`, so rows with dates that are not available for the three periods are not filtered out.

Comment: @GMB: Appreciate your response..I am trying to do the same in Google Bigquery

Comment: In Big query there is no outer apply and cross apply

Comment: So that would be `LEFT JOIN LATERAL … ON 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with each condition (previous month, previous year with same month).

`QUALIFY` is used to filter the specific value of each group (state).

###### Query

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE input_data AS 
SELECT '2022-02-01' as archive, 'AK' as state, 1500 as purchase, 115.0 as purchaserate, 80.0 as fulfilledrate
UNION ALL SELECT '2022-02-01', 'AL', 20000, 117.0, 90.0
UNION ALL SELECT '2022-01-01', 'AK',  1700, 121.0, 65.0
UNION ALL SELECT '2022-01-01', 'AL', 25000,  93.0, 89.0
UNION ALL SELECT '2021-02-01', 'AK',  2100,  70.0, 50.0
UNION ALL SELECT '2021-02-01', 'AL', 32000, 123.0, 60.0
;

WITH
preprocess AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', archive)) as archive_year,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', archive)) as archive_month,
    FROM input_data
)
SELECT
    current_data.archive,
    current_data.state,
    current_data.purchase             as purchase_current_month,
    previous_month_data.purchase      as purchase_previous_month,
    previous_year_same_month.purchase as purchase_previous_year_same_month,

FROM preprocess current_data
LEFT OUTER JOIN preprocess previous_month_data
    ON current_data.state = previous_month_data.state
        AND current_data.archive_year = previous_month_data.archive_year
        AND current_data.archive_month = previous_month_data.archive_month + 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN preprocess previous_year_same_month
    ON current_data.state = previous_year_same_month.state
        AND current_data.archive_year = previous_year_same_month.archive_year + 1
        AND current_data.archive_month = previous_year_same_month.archive_month
-- TO FILTER ONLY THE LAST VALUE OF THE (STATE) GROUP
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY current_data.state
    ORDER BY current_data.archive DESC
) = 1
ORDER BY state ASC
;
```

###### Result

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jiho Choi...Really appreciate your help!..Can you please let me know how I can get the values for state AK and AL for every single archive starting from Jan 2021

Comment: To see every value of archives, you may want to see the result without the `QUALIFY` clause. The `QUALIFY` clause is filtering the value base on `PARTITION`, thus, you may want to filter with different conditions.